Unresolved reference when adding module dependency in Gradle for Compose Multiplatform project
I'm having trouble resolving a module dependency in my Compose Multiplatform project. I have a module named designSystem under the path composeApp:core:designSystem, and I'm trying to include it in my app module. However, I keep encountering unresolved reference issues.

settings.gradle Configuration:
include ':composeApp:core:designSystem'

build.gradle (App Module):
dependencies {implementation(project(":composeApp:core:designSystem"))}


the problem when I am trying to get anything from designSystem module it gives me unresolved reference even if I am importing it
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
